# How to find empty closing tags in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have a few questions relating to Nokogiri in Ruby.

I have an Nokogiri XML document which contains some empty closing tags. Some of these can be nested several levels deep.

For example;

```xml
<Authors>
     <Name>A Name</Name>
     <Titles>
          <Title1>A Book</Title1>
          <Title2/>
     </Titles>
     <Reviews>
          <Review1/>
     </Reviews>
 </Authors>
```

1. Does anyone know a simple way to be able to find these nested empty tags? Or can anyone help with the simplest way to navigate the document to find these elements?
2. Also, in the case of the `<Review>` tags, when I find and remove `<Review1/>`, is there a simple way to check that there are no other siblings and remove the parent tags, which will now contain no other elements?

Comment: Have you tried the [`:empty` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty)? `doc.css(':empty')` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great place for a recursive traversal. Starting at the document root, you can walk children depth-first, cleaning them as you go. If a child has no content, remove it.

```
def clean(node)
  node.children.each do |child|
    clean(child)
    child.remove if child.content.gsub(/\s+/, '').empty?
  end
end
```

You get your wish for part (2) by cleaning the child before removing it - that ensures `<Review1>` is found and removed before `<Reviews>` is considered. If you didn't want to remove now-empty parents, you would swap those lines.

Because your document is formatted for humans to read, lots of nodes contain text nodes with whitespace in them, so the `gsub` cleans that out before considering emptiness.

On your input, this ends up with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Authors>
  <Name>A Name</Name>
  <Titles>
    <Title1>A Book</Title1>
  </Titles>
</Authors>
```